# Get Facebook meta tags with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get Facebook's meta tags from my HTML.

I'm using simple html dom to get all html data from the site.
I've tried with preg_replace, but without luck.

I want for example to get the content of this fb meta tag:

```
<meta content="IMAGE URL" property="og:image" />
```

Hope someone can help! :-)

Comment: Can you provide some more info, like what have you tried, and what does your code looks like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I Was going to suggest to use [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) but it seems to not work (for me) :s

```
<?php
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');
echo $tags['og:image'];
?>
```

But I would rather suggest using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) anyways:

```
<?php
$sites_html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');

$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($sites_html);
$meta_og_img = null;
//Get all meta tags and loop through them.
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    //If the property attribute of the meta tag is og:image
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){ 
        //Assign the value from content attribute to $meta_og_img
        $meta_og_img = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
echo $meta_og_img;
?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: first method doesn't work because get_meta_tags() only pass meta tags with name attributes.

Comment: I see how this makes sense at first glance but after trying to implement it and having it fail, doesn't it result in a recursion problem if the file_get_contents() is calling itself because the PHP parser will be called again and again?

Comment: @J-a-n-u-s It will if it calls itself.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for responding. I ended flipping the whole thing around by building the meta data using PHP in the first place and then just calling the same variables later on when I needed them instead of trying to read the hardcoded html meta data using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As per this method you will get key pair array of fabcebook open graph tags.

```
 $url="http://fbcpictures.in";
 $site_html=  file_get_contents($url);
    $matches=null;
    preg_match_all('~<\s*meta\s+property="(og:[^"]+)"\s+content="([^"]*)~i',     $site_html,$matches);
    $ogtags=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($matches[1]);$i++)
    {
        $ogtags[$matches[1][$i]]=$matches[2][$i];
    }
```

[image: Output of facebook open graph tags]