# Fetch og:image by file_get_contents and preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, metadata, facebook-opengraph, file-get-contents

I'm Using file_get_contents to get og:image from any url.

```
$fooURL = file_get_contents($URLVF['url']);
```

And then I filter property=og:image to get the image from the page and this code below work with most of the websites

```
preg_match("/content='(.*?)' property='og:image'/", $fooURL, $fooImage);
```

But sites like www.howcast.com have deffrent code of og:image like below

```
<meta content='http://attachments-mothership-production.s3.amazonaws.com/images/main-avatar.jpeg' property='og:image'>
```

So to get the image link for above code I need the preg_match to be like this

```
preg_match('/property="og:image" content="(.*?)"/', $fooURL, $fooImage);
```

But of course if I used the code above now the only site will work is howcast and every site else will return nothing

Any idea how can I make the code work with any kind of method the meta code is written or any alternative way to get the image link smoothly

Comment: Use XPATH on a DOMDocument.

Comment: use what str explained, but you can group your pattern like this `(pattern1|pattern2)`

Comment: here also exact answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014196/get-facebook-meta-tags-with-php

Comment: @str I tried this code http://jsfiddle.net/P8PrV/ but the result always NULL, I donw know what i'v done wrong!!

Comment: @Jim `loadHtml` loads HTML, not a URL.

Comment: @str Yes I got it now :), Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with DOMDocument and XPath as @str suggests it:

```
$html = <<<LOD
<html><head>
<meta content='http://attachments-mothership-production.s3.amazonaws.com/images/main-avatar.jpeg' property='og:image'>
</head><body></body></html>
LOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
// or @$doc->loadHTMLFile($URLVF['url']);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$metaContentAttributeNodes = $xpath->query("/html/head/meta[@property='og:image']/@content");
foreach($metaContentAttributeNodes as $metaContentAttributeNode) {
    echo $metaContentAttributeNode->nodeValue . "<br/>";
}
```