# A reliable way to scrape title, description and keywords

Tags: php, curl, title

Currently I'm using CURL to scrape a website. **I want to reliably get the title, description and keywords.**

```
//Parse for the title, description and keywords
if (strlen($link_html) > 0)
{
    $tags = get_meta_tags($link);     // name
    $link_keywords = $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
    $link_description = $tags['description'];
}
```

The only problem is people are now using all kinds of meta tags, such as open graph `<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />`. They also vary the tags a lot `<title> <Title> <TITLE> <tiTle>`. It's very difficult to get these reliably.

I really need some code that will extract these variables consistently. If there is some title, keyword and description provided that it will find it. Because right now it seems very hit and miss.

**Perhaps a way to extract all titles into a titles array?** Then the scraping web developer can choose the best one to record in their database. The same applying to keywords and description.

> This is not a duplicate. I have searched through stackoverflow and
>   nowhere is this solution to place all "title", "keywords" and
>   "description" type tags into arrays.

Comment: you can check first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014196/get-facebook-meta-tags-with-php

Comment: @Armen that relates to opengraph only. I'm talking about some way to get all titles (perhaps in an array?) and all descriptions. So that the web developer can then decide what data to use.

Comment: No through `DOMDocument` in that exmaple you can ready all meta tags which you need and assign it to some result array, you just need to create appropriate `if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='META_NAME'){` cases to search for `og:image`,`keyword`,`description` ... , i can write more detailed example in answer if this answer is not so clear for you

Comment: the problem is that there are so many different formats for title. I'm looking for a solution that looks for the case-insensitive word "title" in a tag and works from there. On the assumption that people are using all kinds of different title formats.

Comment: Actually i don't think so that there is ready made function in php for this, you have to handle all manually also problem with case sensitive meta names can be solved by initial `lowercase()` , but ok lets see what others can suggest you probably there is already ready made php library for this ...

Comment: Since when was stackoverflow a place just for ready-made libraries? I would agree that it's not a place to ask someone to script your website for you. But this is a generic problem that is facing a lot of web developers. They find a lot of individual ways to find the title, description and keywords tags. Sometimes they work sometimes they don't. And there's so many formats for these tags now that you're usually losing the best quality data.

Comment: have alook at http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php#117176 here is some solution to get all metatags like title and meta description also have a look at https://regex101.com/r/oE4oU9/1

Comment: Thanks, having a look now :)

Comment: Just as an FYI, depending on what sites you're scraping and their specific TOS, the legality of this may be questionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `get_meta_tags()` should get you most of what you need, you just need to setup a set of cascading checks that will sample the required field from each metadata system until one is found. For example, something like this:

```
function get_title($url) {
  $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
  $props = get_meta_props($url);
  return @tags["title"] || @props["og:title"] || ...
}
```

The above implementation is obviously not efficient (because if we implemetn all the getters like this you'd reload the URL for each getter), and I didn't implement `get_meta_props()` - which is problematic to implement correctly using `pcre_*` and tedious to implement using `DOMDocument`.

Still a correct implementation is trivial though a lot of work - which is a classic scenario for an external library to solve the problem! Fortunately, there is one for just that - called simply "Embed" and you can find it on [github](https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed), or using composer just run

```
composer require embed/embed
```