# Get description of meta tag from a URL in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am setting up a simple app to save links of interesting articles. I'd like to be able to retrieve the description of the meta tag from the website of the URL or at least the first headline or text that appears in the page that is accessed when accessing that URL, to display this next to the URL:

This is the app so far:
http://ux.machinas.com/mux-feed/

Is there a way to do this in angular?

Comment: Maybe an $http.get to the url, then parse the response html with JavaScript to look for <title> and <meta> tags?

Answer (score -1):

I am facing a similar problem. I am getting a cross-browser script error when trying to get page info with $http.get(), ie `$http.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')`.

I think the best solution is to get the page info on the server, then send to the browser, ie.
$http.get('./api/getPageInfo.php?url=www.myUrl.com/whatever').then....

this thread explains how to get page info in PHP - [Get Facebook meta tags with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014196/get-facebook-meta-tags-with-php)