# Safely uploading and serving images scraped from Open Graph

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security, facebook-opengraph

**This question relates to securing my system and protecting my users when my site scrapes, stores, and embeds Open Graph images** scraped from links to external webpages posted in a public chatboard.

I have a chat forum application (Apache/PHP/WordPress) where users can post links to external pages, and I'd like to safely store and embed the open graph image, title, description, similar to the way Facebook does when you post a link.

Facebook does this by scraping the Open Graph data and stores a local version of the image on their own servers, probably for permanence and performance. I'd like to likewise store the OG image locally, which allows me to resize and smush it, and preserve it for the future.

I've got the scraping working great, using [Open Graph Protocol helper for PHP](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph) on GitHub.

But an example of my concern is demonstrated in the example on the GitHub source itself - it pulls a page from Rotten Tomatoes, and the OG image has this format:

`https://resizing.flixster.com/Er0hIAp55dpRWn5HQTrPc1f2hZE=/740x290/v1.bjs5NzU2NjtqOzE3MDExOzEyMDA7MTEyMDs4NDA`

There is no extension on this URL, and I know that even if it has an extension, that can be wrong, and the image could harbor malicious code that I could expose my users to if I upload and serve the image.

**My current security approach includes**:

- Use PHP's [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to reliably (?) check the file type. If image doesn't match PNG, JPG, GIF, etc., reject it.
- lock down the uploads directory with .htaccess, and explicitly disallow script execution

  ```
  AddHandler cgi-script .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
  Options -ExecCGI
  ```
- store images outside of the web root, and use a PHP function (e.g. [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)) to serve it.
- restrict upload directory (e.g. chmod 770)

**Given my goals (scrape image, process, store, embed) am I missing any security holes that can be further mitigated?  Is there a library or other functions you can recommend to ensure images served this way are (relatively) secure?**

Comment: _“the image could harbor malicious code that I could expose my users to if I upload and serve the image”_ – I rather doubt that would survive resizing though. (Perhaps in EXIF meta data, so you might want to clean/remove that.)

Comment: @CBroe an excellent solution, but [this discussion](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2012/06/encoding-web-shells-in-png-idat-chunks/) about a PNG that survives resizing has me snakebit. Do you think that exploit is too remote, or now that it's documented, a predictable vector?

Comment: My naive hunch is: better to focus on the bigger element of this class of exploits, i.e.: they rely on Local File Inclusion or some other forms of accidental execution vulnerabilities, which definitely should be fixed anyway, in general (regardless of media file types), and if it's done, hacked images should cease to be a real threat, as a by-product.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress, then you can use [Yoast SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) which has built-in opengraph feature.

Refer: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/getting-open-graph-for-your-articles/

Comment: Yoast will create Open Graph for my articles, which is useful, but here specifically I'm concerned about scraping and saving locally images from other pages.  Did I miss features related to that on Yoast?

Comment: I can't guess what is that image format from rotten tomato url which you gave above. Just refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014196/get-facebook-meta-tags-with-php. So you need to pass the users post url dynamically to get the og:image and you can store it. If you got any error add this libxml_use_internal_errors(true); above file_get_contents(). Hope now you can store image on your server and serve it.