# PHP get_meta_tags() not working as I expected

Tags: php, function, meta, get-meta-tags

I wanted to get meta tags (Specially og:title, og:description, and og:image)

I use following code:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('https://www.shoutmeloud.com/review-of-hostgator-webhosting-wordpress.html/');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tags);
```

It returns the following array,

```
Array
(
    [viewport] => width=device-width, initial-scale=1
    [description] => Check out HostGator review for year 2017. This review if written after using Hostgator for 5 years. Is Hostgator Good hosting? Find out answer here
    [twitter:card] => summary_large_image
    [twitter:description] => Check out HostGator review for year 2017. This review if written after using Hostgator for 5 years. Is Hostgator Good hosting? Find out answer here
    [twitter:title] => A Blogger Review of HostGator Shared Hosting Plan
    [twitter:site] => @shoutmeloud
    [twitter:image] => https://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Review-of-Hostgator-Shared-Hosting-Plan.jpg
    [twitter:creator] => @denharsh
    [generator] => Easy Digital Downloads v2.8.14
    [msapplication-tileimage] => https://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-favicon-270x270.png
)
```

PHPFidlle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qe22-3r5n

Why it did not return tags like `og:title, og:description and og:image` even there are on source code of that URL. How do I correct this issue?

Comment: Try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014561/8566549

Answer (score 6):

That's because [`get_meta_tags`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) is looking for the `name` attribute.

> The value of the **name** property becomes the key

All of the tags you are looking for are listed under the `property` attribute.

If you're the owner of the source page, then you could simply add the `name` attribute to the elements with the same value as the `property` attribute.

If not, then you could use something like [`DOMDocument`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) in conjunction with [`file_get_contents`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [`curl`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the specific values in which you're interested.

For example:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.shoutmeloud.com/review-of-hostgator-webhosting-wordpress.html');

$doc = new DOMDocument();

// squelch HTML5 errors
@$doc->loadHTML($content);

$meta = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
foreach ($meta as $element) {
    $tag = [];
    foreach ($element->attributes as $node) {
        $tag[$node->name] = $node->value;
    }
    $tags []= $tag;
}

print_r($tags);
```

Results in:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [charset] => UTF-8
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => viewport
>             [content] => width=device-width, initial-scale=1
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => description
>             [content] => Check out HostGator review for year 2017. This review if written after using Hostgator for 5 years. Is Hostgator Good hosting? Find out answer here
>         )
>
>     [3] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:locale
>             [content] => en_US
>         )
>
>     [4] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:type
>             [content] => article
>         )
>
>     [5] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:title
>             [content] => A Blogger Review of HostGator Shared Hosting Plan
>         )
>
>     [6] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:description
>             [content] => Check out HostGator review for year 2017. This review if written after using Hostgator for 5 years. Is Hostgator Good hosting? Find out answer here
>         )
>
>     [7] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:url
>             [content] => https://www.shoutmeloud.com/review-of-hostgator-webhosting-wordpress.html
>         )
>
>     [8] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:site_name
>             [content] => ShoutMeLoud
>         )
>
>     [9] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:publisher
>             [content] => https://www.facebook.com/shoutmeloud
>         )
>
>     [10] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:author
>             [content] => https://www.facebook.com/denharsh
>         )
>
>     [11] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:tag
>             [content] => hostgator
>         )
>
>     [12] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:tag
>             [content] => Review
>         )
>
>     [13] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:tag
>             [content] => Wordpress Webhosting
>         )
>
>     [14] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:section
>             [content] => Webhosting
>         )
>
>     [15] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:published_time
>             [content] => 2016-08-18T15:51:46+05:30
>         )
>
>     [16] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => article:modified_time
>             [content] => 2017-11-29T23:50:31+05:30
>         )
>
>     [17] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:updated_time
>             [content] => 2017-11-29T23:50:31+05:30
>         )
>
>     [18] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => fb:admins
>             [content] => 100000563323286
>         )
>
>     [19] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:image
>             [content] => https://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Review-of-Hostgator-Shared-Hosting-Plan.jpg
>         )
>
>     [20] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => og:image:secure_url
>             [content] => https://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Review-of-Hostgator-Shared-Hosting-Plan.jpg
>         )
>
>     [21] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => twitter:card
>             [content] => summary_large_image
>         )
>
>     [22] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => twitter:description
>             [content] => Check out HostGator review for year 2017. This review if written after using Hostgator for 5 years. Is Hostgator Good hosting? Find out answer here
>         )
>
>     [23] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => twitter:title
>             [content] => A Blogger Review of HostGator Shared Hosting Plan
>         )
>
>     [24] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => twitter:site
>             [content] => @shoutmeloud
>         )
>
>     [25] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => twitter:image
>             [content] => https://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Review-of-Hostgator-Shared-Hosting-Plan.jpg
>         )
>
>     [26] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => twitter:creator
>             [content] => @denharsh
>         )
>
>     [27] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => generator
>             [content] => WordPress 4.9.1
>         )
>
>     [28] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => generator
>             [content] => Easy Digital Downloads v2.8.14
>         )
>
>     [29] => Array
>         (
>             [property] => fb:pages
>             [content] => 94019601674
>         )
>
>     [30] => Array
>         (
>             [name] => msapplication-TileImage
>             [content] => https://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-favicon-270x270.png
>         )
>
>     [31] => Array
>         (
>             [content] => Hostgator
>             [itemprop] => name
>         )
>
>     [32] => Array
>         (
>             [content] => 1
>             [itemprop] => worstRating
>         )
>
>     [33] => Array
>         (
>             [content] => 4.5
>             [itemprop] => ratingValue
>         )
>
>     [34] => Array
>         (
>             [content] => 5
>             [itemprop] => bestRating
>         )
>
>     [35] => Array
>         (
>             [content] => Hostgator
>             [itemprop] => name
>         )
>
> )
> ```