# Need To Get Featured Image URL From External Site Looking At WP Page

Tags: javascript, php

I need to get the featured image link from a Wordpress page, but I am on an EXTERNAL SITE that has NOTHING to do with Wordpress, so a WP plugin won't help me.  I simply have the URL to the page, and I want to get the featured image link from that.

Here's what I've been able to do so far.

In PHP I used the following to capture the Html of the page:

```
$handle = fopen($domain, 'r');
$content = stream_get_contents($handle);
```

Here's an example of parts from the string that is returned to $content that I'm working with:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="This Is The Headline" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is some text for the story." />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/author/CanWeGetTheImage/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="DaSite" />
```

I need to get from the 4th meta line down, the image link from the og:image property.  (https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image.jpg)

I've tried using strPos to get the position for where og:image begins, but then I can't figure out what to do to capture the image link once I get the position where og:image starts.

```
$string = strpos($content, "og:image");
```

I can get elements using Javascript, but I don't know how to do that from the string I capture in PHP.  I only know how to use Javascript to get an element if I'm loading from the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014196/get-facebook-meta-tags-with-php/12014561#12014561